# Error connecting to Ubuntu Server via FTP

Tags: server, ssh, virtualization, ftp, sftp

I can connect to my Ubuntu Server VM just fine using FTP on Transmit or SSH via Terminal, but I can't connect using FTP. Whenever I try to connect using Transmit, I get this error: `Error -157: invalid reply from server`

Maybe I am missing software on the VM? I don't really know. I'm not a noob at Linux, but I'm not great either. So simplifying your answer would be great.

My host machine is a MacBook running MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `vsftpd` on the server using the command `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` You may also have to reboot the VM/Server.